# Pull Database from Documents Directory

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have been using the following code to pull an sqlite DB from the Supporting Files in my app.  This has worked fine with no problems.

```
NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath ]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TulsaListBars.sqlite"];
BOOL success = [fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", dbPath);
}else{
    NSLog(@"File Exists: %@", dbPath);
}
if(!(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}       
const char *sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE bar = 'yes'";
sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;
if(sqlite3_prepare(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
```

I have no removed the DB from the Supporting Files and put in on a server.  I'm using the following code to pull the DB from the server into my Documents Directory.  I have verified the file is coming over to the Documents Directory and is accurate with all tables.  However, I'm now getting an error 'Problem with prepare statement: no such table: Locations'

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"my web site/TulsaListBars.sqlite"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *appDocDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *storePath = [appDocDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TulsaListBars.sqlite"];
[data writeToFile:storePath atomically:TRUE];
```

Is this an issue with the DB being in my Documents Directory now instead of the Supporting Files?

Update:  I have restarted and reset the simulator and now it appears the DB is not being loaded into the Documents Directory.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataWithContentsOfURL is downloading the database file synchronously, and may not get the whole file.

Change the approach to asynchronous with NSURLConnection and use the delegate method *didReceiveData* to append to a NSMutableData object and *connectionDidFinishLoading* to make use of that object.

Comment: Is there a good tutorial out there that goes through the advantages of one way vs another, proper checks and balances, etc.  I'm new to the remote access of my database, so I want to make sure I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: In the Apple Development Library, the guide 'URL Loading System Programming' has a section called [Using NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-BAJEAIEE) with examples on the steps required.

Comment: The reason asynchronous downloading is required is because TCP/IP delivers data in blocks. If your data is less than the block size, then a synchronous request might be enough. If it is larger however, then the download will arrive in separate blocks and so asynchronous is required to build it incrementally. By using an instance variable of type NSMutableData you can append to this during the download of each block, and the didFinishLoading... method lets you know when it has finished.